# How to fix SQL order by issue with Crystal Report

Tags: c#, sql, crystal-reports-2008

I am facing sorting (order by) issue while binding data table with crystal report. This is my query "SELECT * FROM Payments WHERE (PayDate BETWEEN @startdate and @enddate) order by Id", Query returns sorted record in datatable but when I bind this result to crystal report it gets unsorted. Please suggest solution to this issue.

I have tried this code

```
DbCommand dbComm = BaseDB.CreatestrCommand();
dbComm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Pavti WHERE (PayDate BETWEEN @startdate and @enddate) order by PavtiNo";
//dbComm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Pavti WHERE PayDate BETWEEN " + fdt.ToShortDateString() + " and " + tdt.ToShortDateString() + "  order by PavtiNo";



DbParameter dbParam = dbComm.CreateParameter();
dbParam.ParameterName = "@startdate";
dbParam.Value = fdt;
dbParam.DbType = DbType.Date;
dbParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
dbComm.Parameters.Add(dbParam);

dbParam = dbComm.CreateParameter();
dbParam.ParameterName = "@enddate";
dbParam.Value = tdt;
dbParam.DbType = DbType.Date;
dbParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
dbComm.Parameters.Add(dbParam);

DataTable fieldData;
try
{
    fieldData = BaseDB.ExecuteSelect(dbComm);
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    throw exc;
}
return fieldData;
```

I need sorted records in crystal report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is in the report and not in the query. Use the Report sort expert in the report designer to identify what field(s) to sort on.